# Subdirectory set as subdomain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I have server with Nginx at front and nodejs which run reactjs application and my application is divided to few parts and I want to each part got own subdomain.
Example:

http://192.168.1.1:9000/part1/ --- > http://sub1.example.com/

http://192.168.1.1:9000/part2/ --- > http://sub2.example.com/

I did something like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name sub1.example.com;
   root html;
   index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/part1/;
  }}
```

Server works when i used this config but when I open browser I've got error which telling me about problem with static content.

Server trying take static content from http://127.0.0.1:9000/part1/

Should take from http://127.0.0.1:9000/

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi @doni can you provide the error you're getting relating to 'problem with static content'?

Comment: to clarify you want to serve the content provided by `http://127.0.0.1:9000/part1/` through `http://sub1.example.com`? Because you said 'should take from `http://192.168.1.1:9000/` at the bottom of your question.

Comment: Hi @PeterReid. Yes i want. When I open http://127.0.0.1:9000/part1/ all works but when i open http://sub1.example.com i have problem with static content like images,css etc... Because react static content is at http://127.0.0.1:9000/static/... but nginx trying get content from  http://127.0.0.1:9000/part1/static/...  .

Comment: so you want to serve requests to node path `/part1` through `sub1.example.com` and then the react static content is at `/`?

Comment: Yes @PeterReid.

Comment: are the static files located on the file system or are they being served by the app? If it's the former then my solution below should work, if not then I'll rewrite my solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information something like so might work (repeat for both subdomains obviously)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub1.example.com;
    root /home/usr/react/app/build/static;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
    }

    location @nodejs {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000/part1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

**Explained**

In this case we are first trying to locate the static files if they exist

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
```

If no matching files exist then the request is proxied to the Node.js server on the path `/part1`

```
proxy_pass http://nodejs/part1;
```

Comment: I cannot started nginx when i used the above configuration. 
Error: "proxy_pass cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression." When i remove /part1 from proxy_pass nginx start.
At sub1.example.com is main page "Welcome to nginx!".
If i change url for example to: sub1.example.com/exp i getting error 500. 

Static files are inside react app /home/usr/react/app/build/static.

Comment: I've got same error like before. Also when I set path at root I received  in console browser 403 Forbidden for css/js files. Maybe this is the wine of react...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with React - is there an example architecture similar to that you described anywhere online I could pull down and test out?